# Unity HostData array issues

Tags: unity-game-engine

So my problem is that whenever i try and call the hostData array with a button it returns null, but I know its not null. I even put a debug.log calling the the first member of the HostData array in update() and get when hostData != null it returns every frame but whenever i call it from the button it says its null, i even used if(hostData == null) to verify it. What could possibly cause this?

```
private HostData[] hostData;
private bool refreshing = false;
private Text joinServerText;
private GameObject joinServerButton;
private GameObject startServerButton;
private GameObject refreshServerButton;


void Awake()
{
    joinServerButton = GameObject.Find ("JoinServerButton");
    joinServerText = GameObject.Find("JoinServerText").GetComponent<Text>();
    startServerButton = GameObject.Find ("StartServerButton");
    refreshServerButton = GameObject.Find ("RefreshServerButton");
}

void Start()
{
    joinServerButton.SetActive (false);
}

void StartServer()
{
    bool useNat = !Network.HavePublicAddress();
    Network.InitializeServer(2,25000, !useNat);
    MasterServer.RegisterHost(gameName,"Tutorial Game Name","This is a    tutorial game");
}

void refreshHostList()
{
    MasterServer.RequestHostList(gameName);
    refreshing = true;
}

void Update()
{
    if (refreshing)
    {
        if(MasterServer.PollHostList().Length > 0)
        {
            refreshing = false;
            Debug.Log (MasterServer.PollHostList().Length);
            hostData = MasterServer.PollHostList();
        }
    }

    if(hostData != null)
    {
        joinServerButton.SetActive (true);
        joinServerText.text = hostData[0].gameName;
        Debug.Log ("hostData[0].gameName");
    }

}
//Messages
void OnServerInitialized()
{
    Debug.Log ("Server Initialized!");
}

void OnMasterServerEvent(MasterServerEvent mse)
{
    if(mse == MasterServerEvent.RegistrationSucceeded)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Registered Server");
    }
}

//UI
public void StartSeverButton()
{
    Debug.Log ("Starting Server...");
    StartServer();
}

public void RefreshHostsButton()
{
    Debug.Log ("Refreshing Hosts...");
    refreshHostList();      
}

public void JoinServerButton()
{

    //for(int i=0; i<hostData.Length; i++)
    //{ 
    if (hostData == null)  <--------- My problem
    {
        Debug.Log("hostData is null");
        //Debug.Log (hostData[0].gameName);
        //Network.Connect (hostData[0]);
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually solve problems of mysterious bad value assignment by replacing this:

```
private HostData[] hostData;
```

With this:

```
private HostData[] _hostData;
private HostData[] hostData { get { return _hostData; } set { _hostData=value; Debug.Log("Host data set. Is null?: "+(_hostData == null), this); } }
```

Run it, and you'll immediately see when the variable is being set to null. And maybe you'll discover that the problem isn't what you thought--for example, maybe it's never set, and there are actually multiple instances of that class, and the one that prints the host count isn't the same instance that has the null variable.

Comment: It didnt solve my problem but it did verify that for whatever reason the array wasnt keeping the value. I did find a solution however by just reassigning the value in the button function i called and it seems to have no delay (which is why i created the refreshing variable). Im not sure why it needed to be reassigned but since its only one line of code i can live with this "band-aid"                                                                  public void JoinServerButton()
 {hostData = MasterServer.PollHostList();
  if (hostData != null)
  {
   Debug.Log("hostData is null");
  }
 }

Comment: The last thing to keep in mind is that in C#, arrays are a reference type. When you make the assignment, you don't really have your own array. You have an array that's shared with the library class, and the library class can destroy it if it wants to. I believe this is what's happening, though I'm surprised by that since it seems a bad practice for a library to do that in a garbage-collected language. If you want to be sure, replace the array with a `List<HostData>` instead. That way the only shared references will be to `HostData` objects, not the list itself.

Comment: tried it after seeing your post and got this error " error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.HostData[]' to `System.Collections.Generic.List<UnityEngine.HostData>' ". I bet your right though about the library class destroying the value

Comment: Oh, you'd also have to replace the assignment with `hostData = new List<HostData>(MasterServer.PollHostList());`